# ASP NET MVC - Form in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have a problem in my asp.net view. I'v got a foreach loop, and i can't put my first iteration into my form.

That's the code:

```
<div id="@item.Name" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="row">
        @{int i = 0;}
        @foreach (var prod in item.Products.Where(p => p.Type_Id == item.Id && p.IsDeleted != true))
        {
            using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrderRow", "Orders", new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-inline" }))
            {
                <input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.orderId" name="Order_Id" />
                <input type="hidden" value="@prod.Id" name="ProductID" />
                <input type="hidden" value="@prod.Price" name="Price" />
                <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-bottom:20px">
                    <div align="center">
                        <button style="background-color:transparent; border-color:transparent">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src='@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(String.Format("{0}/{1}", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProdUploadPath"], prod.Image))' style="max-height: 100px" data-toggle="tooltip" title="@prod.Name">
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                if (i % 4 == 3)
                {
                    @:</div><div class="row">
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

And that's how it look:

[image]

As you can see, only first div into first row is out of my form.

Comment: did you need to generate all the form in 1 page? if not, please move your html.beginform out of the loop

Comment: What is the point of this? - you can only submit one form at at time.

Comment: `using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrderRow", "Orders", new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-inline" }))` inside `foreach` loop - this creates multiple form tags but only one can be submitted to action method.

Comment: And as a side note, delete unnecessary `new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }` and you adding the class name as a route value, not a html attribute (your using the wrong overload)

Comment: I've got a grind with many elements, and i need to add them on my list onlick. That's work for everyone except 1st cause it does't have a form.

Answer (score 0):

my suggest if you want save list, use save list not iteration form

example controller here;s the one when i learn mvc hahaha

```
     public ActionResult Create(int? area, string now, string search, string message)
    {
        ViewBag.Area = new SelectList(CoreList.GetDropdown("UnitArea"), "DropdownId", "Value", area);
        ViewBag.SelectedArea = area;

        var newdate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
        IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name, true);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(now))
        {
            DateTime.TryParse(now, culture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out newdate);
        }

        ViewBag.dateFilter = newdate.ToString(CultureInfo
            .GetCultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)
            .DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);

        ViewBag.Search = search;
        var attendances = (from p in db.MstUnitDriverPairings

                           join x in db.TrnAttendanceUnits
                           .Where(o => o.PresentDate.Value.Year == newdate.Year &&
                           o.PresentDate.Value.Month == newdate.Month &&
                           o.PresentDate.Value.Day == newdate.Day)
                           on p.UnitId equals x.UnitId into j1
                           from x in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()

                           join v in db.TrnAttendanceUnits.OrderByDescending(o => o.PresentDate).Where(o => o.ClockOut == null && o.PresentDate < newdate)
                           on p.UnitId equals  v.UnitId into jd1
                           from v in jd1.DefaultIfEmpty()

                           join y in db.TrnAttendanceDrivers.Where(o => o.PresentDate == newdate)
                           on p.DriverId equals y.DriverId into j2
                           from y in j2.DefaultIfEmpty()

                           join z in db.TrnAttendanceDrivers.OrderByDescending(o => o.PresentDate).Where(o => o.ClockOut == null && o.PresentDate < newdate)
                            on p.DriverId equals z.DriverId into jd2
                           from z in jd2.DefaultIfEmpty()

                           where (area == null ? true : p.MstUnits.UnitArea == area)
                           && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) ? true : p.MstDrivers.DriverName.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                           || p.MstUnits.PoliceNo.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()))
                           && p.MstUnits.UnitPrimary == true

                           select new Attendance
                           {
                               DriverId = p.DriverId,
                               DriverName = p.MstDrivers.DriverName,
                               DriverIn = y.ClockIn == null ? false : true,
                               DriverOut = y.ClockOut == null ? false : true,
                               DriverInDate = y.ClockIn,
                               DriverInDateBefore = z.ClockIn,
                               DriverOutDate = y.ClockOut,
                               DriverOutDateBefore = z.ClockOut,

                               UnitId = p.UnitId,
                               PoliceNumber = p.MstUnits.PoliceNo,
                               UnitIn = x.ClockIn == null? false : true,
                               UnitOut = x.ClockOut == null ? false : true,
                               UnitInDate = x.ClockIn,
                               UnitInDateBefore = v.ClockIn,
                               UnitOutDate = x.ClockOut,
                               UnitOutDateBefore = v.ClockOut
                           }).ToList();

        return View(attendances);
    }
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AttendanceSave(List<Attendance> Models, string presentDate, int? area, string search)
    {
        string message = string.Empty;

        var newdate = new DateTime();
        IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name, true);

        if (DateTime.TryParse(presentDate, culture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out newdate))
        {
            foreach (var item in Models)
            {
                TrnAttendanceDriver trnAttendanceDriver = db.TrnAttendanceDrivers.FirstOrDefault(o => o.PresentDate == newdate && o.DriverId == item.DriverId);
                TrnAttendanceUnit trnAttendanceUnit = db.TrnAttendanceUnits.FirstOrDefault(o => o.PresentDate == newdate && o.UnitId == item.UnitId);

                if (trnAttendanceDriver != null)
                {
                    if (item.DriverIn && item.DriverInDate != null) trnAttendanceDriver.ClockIn = item.DriverInDate;
                    if (item.DriverOut && item.DriverOutDate != null)
                    {
                        trnAttendanceDriver.ClockOut = item.DriverOutDate;
                        trnAttendanceDriver.Status = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (item.DriverIn)
                    {
                        var newDriverAttendance = new TrnAttendanceDriver();
                        newDriverAttendance.DriverId = item.DriverId;
                        newDriverAttendance.ClockIn = item.DriverInDate;
                        newDriverAttendance.PresentDate = newdate;
                        newDriverAttendance.Status = true;
                        db.TrnAttendanceDrivers.Add(newDriverAttendance);
                    }
                }

                if (trnAttendanceUnit != null)
                {
                    if (item.UnitIn && item.UnitInDate != null) trnAttendanceUnit.ClockIn = item.UnitInDate;
                    if (item.UnitOut && item.UnitOutDate != null)
                    {
                        trnAttendanceUnit.ClockOut = item.UnitOutDate;
                        trnAttendanceUnit.Status = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (item.UnitIn)
                    {
                        var newUnitAttendance = new TrnAttendanceUnit();
                        newUnitAttendance.UnitId = item.UnitId;
                        newUnitAttendance.ClockIn = item.UnitInDate;
                        newUnitAttendance.PresentDate = newdate;
                        newUnitAttendance.Status = true;
                        db.TrnAttendanceUnits.Add(newUnitAttendance);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch //(Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index","Transaction/Attendance", new {area, search, message, now = presentDate });
    }
```

here's the model

```
public class Attendance
{
    public int DriverId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string DriverName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Driver In")]
    public bool DriverIn { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? DriverInDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? DriverOutDateBefore { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? DriverInDateBefore { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Driver Out")]
    public bool DriverOut { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? DriverOutDate { get; set; }
    public int UnitId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Police Number")]
    public string PoliceNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Unit In")]
    public bool UnitIn { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? UnitInDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? UnitOutDateBefore { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? UnitInDateBefore { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Unit Out")]
    public bool UnitOut { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? UnitOutDate { get; set; }
}
```

and here's view

```html
@model List<Solution.Web.Areas.Transaction.Models.Attendance>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<nav class="navbar navbar-white" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav2">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle</span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand">Search</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav2">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.DropDownList("Area", string.Empty)
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="now" id="dateFilter" class="form-control datepicker" value="@ViewBag.dateFilter" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="Search" class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.Search" placeholder="Search" />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
@using (Html.BeginForm("AttendanceSave", "Attendance", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="presentDate" value="@ViewBag.dateFilter" />
    <input type="hidden" name="area" value="@ViewBag.SelectedArea" />
    <input type="hidden" name="search" value="@ViewBag.Search" />
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Attendance</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="3">
                        Driver
                    </th>
                    <th colspan="3">
                        Unit
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        In
                        &nbsp;
                        @Html.CheckBox("drivercheckInHead")
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Out
                        &nbsp;
                        @Html.CheckBox("drivercheckOutHead")
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Police Number
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        In
                        &nbsp;
                        @Html.CheckBox("unitcheckInHead")
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Out
                        &nbsp;
                        @Html.CheckBox("unitcheckOutHead")
                    </th>
                </tr>

                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
                {

                    <tr>
                        @Html.Hidden("Models[" + i + "].DriverId", Model[i].DriverId)
                        @Html.Hidden("Models[" + i + "].UnitId", Model[i].UnitId)
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].DriverName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if (Model[i].DriverIn && Model[i].DriverOut)
                            {
                                @Html.Hidden("Models[" + i + "].DriverIn", Model[i].DriverIn)
                                @Html.Hidden("Models[" + i + "].DriverInDate", Model[i].DriverInDate)
                                @Model[i].DriverInDate.Value.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm")
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (Model[i].DriverOutDateBefore == null && Model[i].DriverInDateBefore != null)
                                {
                                    <label class="label label-danger">
                                        @Model[i].DriverInDateBefore.Value.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm")
                                    </label>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            @Html.CheckBox("Models[" + i + "].DriverIn", Model[i].DriverIn, new { @class = "drivercheckIn" })
                                        </span>
                                        @Html.TextBox("Models[" + i + "].DriverInDate", Model[i].DriverInDate, new { @class = "datetimepicker drivercheckInDate" })
                                    </div>
                                }
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if (Model[i].DriverIn && Model[i].DriverOut)
                            {
                                @Html.Hidden("Models[" + i + "].DriverOut", Model[i].DriverOut)
                                @Html.Hidden("Models[" + i + "].DriverOutDate", Model[i].DriverOutDate)
                                @Model[i].DriverOutDate.Value.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm")
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (Model[i].DriverIn)
                                {
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            @Html.CheckBox("Models[" + i + "].DriverOut", Model[i].DriverOut, new { @class = "drivercheckOut" })
                                        </span>
                                        @Html.TextBox("Models[" + i + "].DriverOutDate", Model[i].DriverOutDate, new { @class = "datetimepicker drivercheckOutDate" })
                                    </div>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <span class="label label-info">Need driver in</span>
                                }

                            }
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].PoliceNumber)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if (Model[i].UnitIn && Model[i].UnitOut)
                            {
                                @Html.Hidden("Models[" + i + "].UnitIn", Model[i].UnitIn)
                                @Html.Hidden("Models[" + i + "].UnitIn", Model[i].UnitInDate)
                                @Model[i].UnitInDate.Value.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm")
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (Model[i].UnitOutDateBefore == null && Model[i].UnitInDateBefore != null)
                                {
                                    <label class="label label-danger">
                                        @Model[i].UnitInDateBefore.Value.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm")
                                    </label>
                                }
                                else
                                {

                                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            @Html.CheckBox("Models[" + i + "].UnitIn", Model[i].UnitIn, new { @class = "unitcheckIn" })
                                        </span>
                                        @Html.TextBox("Models[" + i + "].UnitInDate", Model[i].UnitInDate, new { @class = "datetimepicker unitcheckInDate" })
                                    </div>
                                }
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if (Model[i].UnitIn && Model[i].UnitOut)
                            {
                                @Html.Hidden("Models[" + i + "].UnitOut", Model[i].UnitOut)
                                @Html.Hidden("Models[" + i + "].UnitOutDate", Model[i].UnitOutDate)
                                @Model[i].UnitOutDate.Value.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm")
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (Model[i].UnitIn)
                                {
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            @Html.CheckBox("Models[" + i + "].UnitOut", Model[i].UnitOut, new { @class = "unitcheckOut" })
                                        </span>
                                        @Html.TextBox("Models[" + i + "].UnitOutDate", Model[i].UnitOutDate, new { @class = "datetimepicker unitcheckOutDate" })
                                    </div>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <span class="label label-info">Need unit in</span>
                                }
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
        @if (Model.Count() > 0)
        {

            <div class="panel-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">&nbsp;Submit</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

hope this helps, sorry for my bad codes, hehehe